# Does Mac Pro 2013 support 5 GHz Wi-Fi?

Tags: mac, network, wifi, mac-pro

Does the Mac Pro 2013 support 5 GHz Wi-Fi? Can't find this information on Apple product page.

Comment: 5Ghz has been supported for a long time - 2008 Mac Pro here happily running it right now [no ac of course, just n]

Comment: @Tetsujin But the 5GHz WiFi card wasn't supported on the original build, was it? I know I have 5GHz now since I've upgraded to a High Sierra compatible card...

Comment: tbh, I'm unsure whether I retro-fitted that one with a BTLE card or not. You may be right. I've tweaked too many cheese-graters to remember what I did to which now, sorry ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Wireless**
>
> - 802.11ac Wi-Fi wireless networking

[Mac Pro (Late 2013) - Technical Specifications - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp697)

> 802.11ac uses the 5GHz band

[802.11ac vs 802.11n WiFi: What's The Difference? - Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/gordonkelly/2014/12/30/802-11ac-vs-802-11n-wifi-whats-the-difference/)